# Why terminate is called after throwing an instance of 'range error' what(): 'Range Error' -1

Tags: c++, c++11, atom-editor

I don't know why the compiler is returning this error. I searched Google but I didn't find anything.

```
#include"std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
  vector<double>numbers;
  cout<<"Enter any two numbers:\n";
  double two_numbers;
  //loop
  while(cin>>two_numbers){
    numbers.push_back(two_numbers);
    double vector_size = numbers.size();
    double two = 2;
    double formula_equal = 1.0/100;
    double od_ev = fmod(vector_size , two);
    //checking the conditions
    if(od_ev == 0)
      if(numbers[vector_size-1] > numbers[vector_size - 2])
        cout<<"The larger value is: "<<numbers[vector_size - 1]<<'\n'
            <<"The smaller value is: "<<numbers[vector_size - 2]<<'\n';
        if(numbers[vector_size-1] - numbers[vector_size - 2] < formula_equal)
          cout<<"These numbers are almost equal.";

      else if(numbers[vector_size-1] < numbers[vector_size - 2])
        cout<<"The larger value is: "<<numbers[vector_size - 2]<<'\n'
            <<"The smaller value is: "<<numbers[vector_size - 1]<<'\n';
        if(numbers[vector_size-2] - numbers[vector_size - 1] < formula_equal)
          cout<<"these numbers are almost equal.";

      else if(numbers[vector_size-1] == numbers[vector_size - 2])
        cout<<numbers[vector_size-1]<<" is equal to  "<<numbers[vector_size - 2]<<'\n';

      }
  }
```

Comment: Why are you using `double` values for indexes? That's just asking for trouble. `vector_size`, `two` and `od_ev` should all be `int` (or `unsigned`)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Also, I highly recommend reading "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". We don't care what your experience is, it's really not important. We do care very much that you've done your research and put in the effort and then you ask a good question.

Answer (score 4):

My Observations:

1. The problem is at line:

   ```
   numbers[vector_size-1] > numbers[vector_size - 2]
   ```

   At first iteration of your for loop, `vector_size` might be 1 and `vector_size - 2` will be -1. You need to handle that case and don't allow to access any element beyond `[0, vector.size())`.
2. You can simply use `unsigned` as data-type for index variable. That is, `vector_size` should be unsigned. Also, you should consider using [at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) method of `vector` class.

   > Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos, with bounds checking. If pos is not within the range of the container, an exception of type std::out_of_range is thrown.
3. It's good practice to use braces `{}` around multi-lines statement under `if` statement and it's necessary to put braces around multiple statements that should be executed only if `if` conditions becomes `true`. What you were expecting that the code under your `if(od_ev == 0)` will be executed only when `od_ev` will be zero. However, compiler is only considering the statement:

   ```
   if(numbers[vector_size-1] > numbers[vector_size - 2])
        cout << "The larger value is: " << numbers[vector_size - 1] << '\n'
            << "The smaller value is: " << numbers[vector_size - 2] << '\n';
   ```

   To be part of the `if` statement and the rest of the statements will be executed irrespective of `od_ev`'s value. That could be reason that you index checking mechanism is not working as expected.
4. I don't think you need to store all of the number input-ed by the user in a `vector` as you are only comparing last two values entered by the user. You can come up with a better implementation which doesn't make use of the vector.

Answer (score 3):

Let's fix indentation:

```
if(od_ev == 0)
    if(numbers[vector_size-1] > numbers[vector_size - 2])
        cout<<"The larger value is: "<<numbers[vector_size - 1]<<'\n'
            <<"The smaller value is: "<<numbers[vector_size - 2]<<'\n';
if(numbers[vector_size-1] - numbers[vector_size - 2] < formula_equal)
    cout<<"These numbers are almost equal.";
else if(numbers[vector_size-1] < numbers[vector_size - 2])
    cout<<"The larger value is: "<<numbers[vector_size - 2]<<'\n'
        <<"The smaller value is: "<<numbers[vector_size - 1]<<'\n';
if(numbers[vector_size-2] - numbers[vector_size - 1] < formula_equal)
    cout<<"these numbers are almost equal.";
else if(numbers[vector_size-1] == numbers[vector_size - 2])
    cout<<numbers[vector_size-1]<<" is equal to  "<<numbers[vector_size - 2]<<'\n';
```

If you do not use `{}` then the body of an `if` is only a single statement, hence you are accessing the vector out-of-bounds in the first iteration.

For illustration, consider this:

```
if (number.size() > 1) 
     std::cout << number.size();
     std::cout << number[0];
```

Which correctly formatted is:

```
if (number.size() > 1) 
    std::cout << number.size();
std::cout << number[0];
```

and probably should have been:

```
if (number.size() > 1) {
    std::cout << number.size();
    std::cout << number[0];
}
```

I find your `vector_size` rather confusing. Use `numbers.size()` (it has constant complexity, not linear as one might expect). Also use the vectors `at` method for better diagnostics when you are not 100% certain to access only valid indices.

Also don't use `double` for an index, and `double two = 2;` is a complete no-go. If you really want a `two` then at the very least make it `const` so that `two = 3;` is not possible.